# Updating model does not always result in updated view

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm using SAPUI5 to make an application and I'm having an issue with an update to the model not being reflected immediately in the view.

A slightly simplified scenario: I created a text field that is taking its text from the model:

```
currentText = new sap.m.Text({
    width: '100%',
    text: '{/currentTrip/perHour}'
});
```

Then I create a select and attach a change handler:

```
sourceSelect.attachChange(oController.changeTripSource);
```

Inside that controller function I'm updating the view model:

```
var model = this.getView().getModel().getData();
model.currentTrip.perHour = 5;
```

All the things I do with this number flowing from this change event work (like updating a connected graph, which uses this number directly). The view itself however will not reflect the change to the model until I take *another* action like push a button or something. I'm not understanding why that is, or what triggers UI5 to check the changed values to the model and update the view. Does anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: See the answer by @matbtt; you should never update model properties directly, always use `model.setProperty("/path/to/your/property", oSomeData);` -- and `getProperty("/path/to/your/property");` for retrieving data from the model

Comment: For other readers: this answer might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48157104/5846045

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you call `setProperty()` on the model directly? This saves you superfluous calls to update your bindings as the model will do it internally.

```js
model.setProperty("/currentTrip/perHour", 5);
```

By the way, I don't see why `updateBindings()` shall work while refresh does not. Both methods call the `checkUpdate()` behind the curtains.

Comment: The connection between control and model is established by a binding object, which is created if you bind an aggregation or a property to a model. So every control has a knowledge about its binding. Vice versa the model holds an array of all its bindings as well.

Answer (score 2):

Always good practice to call `updateBindings()` whenever data is updating. Try:

```js
 model.updateBindings()
```