# attachChange callback not fired for getBinding("text") of sap.m.Button

Tags: sapui5

```
onInit(): function{
    this._oSelectedTrainingsModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel([]);
    this.getView().setModel(this._oSelectedTrainingsModel, "selectedTrainings");
},

onAfterRendering: function() {
    this.getView().byId("ViewSelectionButton").getBinding("text").attachChange(this._onTextUpdated, this);
},
```

In the XML view I have this binding:

```
<Button id="ViewSelectionButton"
    class="magnificationPrep"
    icon="sap-icon://cart-full"
    tooltip="Share"
    text="{i18n>viewTrainingsButton} ({= %{selectedTrainings>/}.length })"
    press="handlePressViewSelection"
/>
```

At some point in the controller, an object is added to the `_oSelectedTrainingsModel`:

```
this._oSelectedTrainingsModel.getProperty("/").push(oNewSelection);
```

At this point, the bound text property is changed and thus I'm expecting a call to the callback function `_onTextUpdated`.

The model is empty, this is probably part of the issue?

[image: ...getBinding("text") object in onAfterRendering()]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe change event is not triggered because of the way you have bound your model and Text property of Button.

Due to expression binding, ONE-WAY-BINDING has occured, meaning value will be changed in MODEL only and will not be reflected back in UI. See Image below:

[image]

To Solve the problem, I manually triggered an refresh event, which will update all the binding(forcefully) and hence, change event of Button Text was triggered.

So, code:

```
    this.getView().getModel('newModel').getProperty("/").push({});
    this.getView().getModel('newModel').refresh(true);
```

where newModel is my named model.

However, while debugging, I found two problems: :(

1. Why is change event triggered twice after manual refresh ?
2. Shouldn't onChange() be triggered if I do:

`this.byId('btn2').setText('Hey1!!')`  ? But it wasn't.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: To answer your questions.. [1]: The change event is triggered twice because there are two bindings involved. The respective module is CompositeBinding which cannot be seen in that UI5 inspector extension. [2]: The change handler should *not* be triggered if you change the text from the UI since the `text` is bound with one-way.

Answer (score 1):

In order to update the UI via model in cases like this, the **model has to use `setProperty`** which calls the internal `checkUpdate` method and eventually fires the [**`change`** event](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.model.Binding#events/change), notifying all listening ManagedObjects when a change is detected.

Please avoid manipulating the array on the same instance directly, e.g. via `getProperty(...).push`, since `getProperty` **does not** call `checkUpdate` and thus bypasses triggering the `change` event. Instead:

#### Create a new array

```js
const path = "...";
const oldArray = myModel.getProperty(path); // returns: array reference (not a copy)
const newArray = oldArray.concat(myObject); // returns: new array
myModel.setProperty(path, newArray, null, true); // oldArray !== newArray --> change detected
// No myModel.refresh() required
```

This alone is sufficient to update the UI thanks to the [**one-way**](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/68b9644a253741e8a4b9e4279a35c247) data binding:

> One-way binding means a binding **from** the model **to** the view. Any value changes in the model update all corresponding bindings and the view..

Here is a demo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48226884/5846045

---

Btw: the module returned by `getBinding("text")` in your case is a `CompositeBinding` since multiple bindings are involved in one ManagedObject property. The visibility of [`CompositeBinding#attachChange` **is protected.**](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.model.CompositeBinding#methods/attachChange) Non-public methods must not be used on an application code level so that the app stays compatible with future SAPUI5 framework code changes (e.g. security patches). See the topics *[JSDocs Visibility Tags](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/b0d5fe2f1b0b497cbd67cd5a1d35fa4c)* and *[Compatibility Rules](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/91f087396f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070)* for more information.